# A symbol table with protection issues

Tags: macros, protected-macro

I wanted to create a table of symbols that is easy to read in LaTeX, so something like:

```
\begin{tabular}{*4M}
     <    & \le     & \ll   & \lll    \\
     >    & \ge     & \gg   & \ggg    \\
     \ne  & \approx & \prec & \preceq \\
     \sim & \simeq  & \succ & \succeq \\
\end{tabular}
```

and that produces both the symbols and command sequences when TeXed, so something like:

[image]

My code below almost does what I want except that, as shown above, `\ne` has unwanted *protection*. Is there a straightforward way around this? I have tried:

- using `\detokenize` (see below)
- using `\string` (doesn't compile)
- using `\cs_to_str:N` from [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/interface3)
- using [fancyvrb](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb)

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Here is the code the produces the output above:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amssymb}% load the AMS symbols
\usepackage[verb]{collcell}
\newcommand\showSymbol[1]{\hbox to 8em{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}$#1$}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\showSymbol}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{*4M}
       <    & \le     & \ll   & \lll    \\
       >    & \ge     & \gg   & \ggg    \\
       \ne  & \approx & \prec & \preceq \\
       \sim & \simeq  & \succ & \succeq \\
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that at the beginning of table cells, TeX is expanding tokens looking for `\omit` or `\span` (for `\multicolumn` and such), so it expands `\ne` to `\protect\ne␣`, and `\protect` is `\relax` which (is not expandable so) is left alone and only then the table template is inserted with `\collectcell\showSymbol`, but at this point `\ne` is already expanded.

There are several ways you can work around this, but they boil down to either:

1. Look at the expanded `\ne` (or whatever command) and check that the first token is `\protect` and typeset the second in that case, or
2. Add something to stop TeX from expanding `\ne`.

For option 1 you can define `\showSymbol` like this (MWE 1 below):

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand\showSymbol[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\@car#1\@nil\protect\@empty
    \expandafter\@showSymbol\expandafter{\@cdr#1\@nil}%
  \else
    \@showSymbol{#1}%
  \fi}
\newcommand\@showSymbol[1]{%
  \hbox to 8em{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}\hss}$#1$}
\makeatother
```

The line `\expandafter\ifx\@car#1\@nil\protect\@empty` will `\ifx`-compare the first token of `#1` with with `\protect` (the `\@empty` is there for safety), and if so pass the remaining tokens to `\@showSymbol`.  Note that this will pass `\ne␣` rather than `\ne` to be typeset, so you might need to trim the trailing space.

For option 2 (MWE 2 below), quick and dirty, you can prefix `\ne` with `\noexpand`.  When TeX expands `\noexpand`, it will temporarily do `\let\ne\relax`, and then the newly-redefined `\ne` will stop the expansion (and `\ne` will be restored to its original meaning).  Then, when `\collectcell` does its job, `\ne` will be there, safe and sound:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{*4M}
  \noexpand\ne & \approx & \prec & \preceq \\
  <            & \le     & \ll   & \lll    \\
  >            & \ge     & \gg   & \ggg    \\
  \sim         & \simeq  & \succ & \succeq \\
\end{tabular}
```

---

MWE 1:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amssymb}% load the AMS symbols
\usepackage[verb]{collcell}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\showSymbol[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\@car#1\@nil\protect\@empty
    \expandafter\@showSymbol\expandafter{\@cdr#1\@nil}%
  \else
    \@showSymbol{#1}%
  \fi}
\newcommand\@showSymbol[1]{%
  \hbox to 8em{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}\hss}$#1$}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\showSymbol}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*4M}
  \ne  & \approx & \prec & \preceq \\
  <    & \le     & \ll   & \lll    \\
  >    & \ge     & \gg   & \ggg    \\
  \sim & \simeq  & \succ & \succeq \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

MWE 2:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amssymb}% load the AMS symbols
\usepackage[verb]{collcell}
\newcommand\showSymbol[1]{\hbox to 8em{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}\hss}$#1$}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\collectcell\showSymbol}l<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*4M}
  \noexpand\ne & \approx & \prec & \preceq \\
  <            & \le     & \ll   & \lll    \\
  >            & \ge     & \gg   & \ggg    \\
  \sim         & \simeq  & \succ & \succeq \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\robustify\ne`?

Comment: @JosephWright I didn't want to raise an existential issue for `\protect` ;-)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! I decided to use the `\noexpand` version, with the `\noexpand` placed at the end of the proceeding line to that it is "out of the way".

Comment: @Andrew You can also do `\let\n\noexpand` and use `\n`, if you promise not to show that to anyone else ;-)

Comment: I'm using this to show students LaTex commands, so I want to minimise the use of technicalities and should not teach them bad habits:) To this end I've switched back to using `\string` instead of `\detokenize` as this looks less cryptic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a different approach, namely to just list the symbols we want to make a table of and let TeX do the splitting.

The trailing optional argument (default 4) is for the number of pairs of columns; the first optional argument is for a title.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\symboltable}{O{}mO{4}}
 {
  \andrew_symboltable:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__andrew_symboltable_tl
\seq_new:N \l__andrew_symboltable_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andrew_symboltable:nnn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pc}
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__andrew_symboltable_seq { #2 }
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_clear:N \l__andrew_symboltable_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__andrew_symboltable_tl
     {
      \multicolumn{\int_eval:n { 2*(#3) } } { @{}c@{} } { #1 } \\ \midrule
     }
   }
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__andrew_symboltable_seq
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__andrew_symboltable_tl
     {
      \texttt{ \token_to_str:N ##2 } & $##2$
     }
    \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn { ##1 } { #3 } = 0 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__andrew_symboltable_tl { \\ }
     }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__andrew_symboltable_tl { & }
     }
   }
   \int_compare:nF { \int_mod:nn { \seq_count:N \l__andrew_symboltable_seq } { #3 } = 0 }
    {
     \tl_put_right:Nn \l__andrew_symboltable_tl { \\ }
    }
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} *{ #3 }{ l@{\hspace{6pt}}l } @{} }
  \toprule
  \tl_use:N \l__andrew_symboltable_tl
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\symboltable{
  <,\le,\ll,\lll,>,\ge,\gg,\ggg,\ne,\approx,
  \prec,\preceq,\sim,\simeq,\succ,\succeq
}

\bigskip

\symboltable[Relation symbols]{
  <,\le,\ll,\lll,>,\ge,\gg,\ggg,\ne,\approx,
  \prec,\preceq,\sim,\simeq,\succ,\succeq
}[5]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This is nice, and clearly a "better" solution on some level, but it doesn't meet my first aim of being "easy to read in LaTeX" (In my use-case I'm not able to hide the code in a style file, but nor do I want to). The intended audience is familiar with `tabular` environments and the `array` package, which is why  took the approach above. At this stage, sadly, LaTeX3 is a step too far.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure that exposing the code to create such tables is good for beginners anyway.